# Sum of a particular column in a csv file

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, csv, dictionary

There is a csv file, say `A.csv`, having content:

```
Place,Hotel,Food,Fare

Norway,Regal,NonVeg,5000    
Poland,Jenny,Italiano,6000    
Norway,Suzane,Vegeterian,4000   
Norway,Regal,NonVeg,5000
```

I have to parse this csv and obtain an output by passing arguments in command prompt.

Example 1:

```
mycode.py Place
```

Desired output is:

```
Place,Fare    
Norway,14000  
Poland,6000
```

Example 2:

```
mycode.py Place Hotel
```

Desired output is:

```
Place,Hotel,Fare
Norway,Regal,10000  
Poland,Jenny,6000  
Norway,Suzane,4000
```

So it is clear from the above example that no matter what you pass as argument it gives you the sum of the `Fare` header for the common ones.

Below is my code and I am able to pass arguments and get an output, but I am stuck in sum of `Fare`. Can any one help me with this.

```
import sys
import csv
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

Data = []
Result = []
Final = []
Argvs = []
argv_len = len(sys.argv)
index = 0
input = ''

file = open('A.csv', 'rb')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        Data.append(row)

    for x in range(1, argv_len):
        Argvs.append(sys.argv[x])
    Argvs.append('Fare')

    for input in Argvs:
        for y in range(0, len(Data[0])):
            if(input == Data[0][y]):
                for z in range(1, len(Data)):
                    Result.append(Data[z][y])                   
                break       
        Final.append(Result)
        Result = []

    New = []
    NewFinal = []
    for x in range(0, len(Final[0])):
        for y in range(0, len(Final)):
            New.append(Final[y][x])
        NewFinal.append(New)
        New = []
    out = {}
    for a in NewFinal:
        out.setdefault(a[0],[]).append(int(a[-1]))
    with open("output.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file,  dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(Argvs)
        for k,v in out.iteritems():
            writer.writerow((k,sum(v)))
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
finally:
    file.close()
```

I edit the code and tried to group it. Now I am able to get the aggregate of the `Fare` but not the desired output.

So when I am passing:

```
mycode.py Place Hotel
```

Instead of:

```
Place,Hotel,Fare  
Norway,Regal,10000  
Poland,Jenny,6000  
Norway,Suzane,4000
```

I am getting:

```
Place,Hotel,Fare  
Norway,14000  
Poland,6000
```

Comment: What do you mean "stuck in sum of count"? You don't do anything with `'Count'`; it's not a header in the data so will never get added to `Final`. You don't seem to have any code for summarising the data, your code so far just gets the columns without any grouping. Also, `'State' != 'Place'`.

Comment: By `'Count'` do you mean `'Fare'`? If so, that's why you aren't getting anywhere; your "headers" to retrieve have to be consistent with the actual data. Why does your second example not have the header `'Hotel'`?

Comment: That doesn't look like CSV ...

Comment: Extremely sorry.I was absent minded while creating the example and posting my actual code. My bad :( .Edited the code.Hope it gives a better idea now. @jonrsharpe

Comment: Hope now it looks like an csv file @Yuki

Comment: You have only addressed one of my comments. So far you don't attempt to aggregate the fares.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that is where i need help.How to group and aggregate the column.

Comment: @vivs have you tried *anything*? Do you have thoughts on how you might approach it? What have you searched for?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried using `import collection` `collections.defaultdict(list)` but unable to group it. :(

Comment: @jonrsharpe hi i gave it try with this `out = {}
 for a in NewFinal:
  out.setdefault(a[0],[]).append(int(a[-1]))
 with open("output.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
  writer = csv.writer(csv_file,  dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
  writer.writerow(Argvs)
  for k,v in out.iteritems():
   writer.writerow((k,sum(v))) `

Comment: @jonrsharpe did the editing.

Comment: *"I edit the code and tried to group it. Now I am able to get the aggregate of the `Fare` but not the desired output."* - where is **that** code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe You can check the code i have edited the original one itself. I used dictionary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51424/discussion-between-vivs-and-jonrsharpe)

Answer (score 1):

Finally i managed to get my desired output.
Below i am sharing the final code.    \

```
import sys
import csv

Data = []
Result = []
Final = []
Argvs = []
argv_len = len(sys.argv)
index = 0
input = ''

file = open('A.csv', 'rb')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        Data.append(row)

    for x in range(1, argv_len):
        Argvs.append(sys.argv[x])
    Argvs.append('Fare')

    for input in Argvs:
        for y in range(0, len(Data[0])):
            if(input == Data[0][y]):
                for z in range(1, len(Data)):
                    Result.append(Data[z][y])                   
                break       
        Final.append(Result)
        Result = []

    New = []
    NewFinal = []
    for x in range(0, len(Final[0])):
        for y in range(0, len(Final)):
            New.append(Final[y][x])
        NewFinal.append(New)
        New = []
    out = {}
    for a in NewFinal:
        count_val = a[-1]
        del a[-1]
        key_val = ','.join(a)
        out.setdefault(key_val.strip('"'),[]).append(int(count_val))
    with open("output.csv", "wb") as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',',quotechar=' ')
        writer.writerow(Argvs)
        for k,v in out.iteritems():
            writer.writerow((k,sum(v)))
except Exception,e:
    print str(e)
finally:
    file.close()
```